bulma 1.0 gives the error `@use rules must be written before any other rules`
I just upgraded to bulma v1.0 and I'm getting this error:
ERROR in ./src/app.sass
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
@use rules must be written before any other rules.
  ╷
2 │ @use "bulma/sass/base"
  │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  src/app.sass 2:1  root stylesheet

First, I put the @use at the top of app.sass.  No help, so I removed everything else so app.sass is currently only a single line (that @use statement.)
Versions in use:
± npm ls sass sass-loader bulma
blah@2.3.0 /Users/blabhla/blal
├── bulma@1.0.2
├─┬ sass-loader@16.0.3
│ └── sass@1.80.5 deduped
└── sass@1.80.5

